# How to create app which suport both bearer only as well as confidential login using keycloak

Tags: single-sign-on, openid, keycloak

I'm implementing the SSO for my web-app. App-1 (Browser Login) is confidential and working fine which have a rest call to App-2 which bearer only. User can also login to App-2 with browser but when i tried it says Bearer-Only not supported for browser login. Can anyone please help how to implement the App-2 which will support both.Below is the configuration of standalone.xml:
   [image]

Comment: Please, don't post code as image

Answer (score 1):

Bearer-only and confidential accesses don't provide mutually exclusive features. Both allow the resource access once you have a valid access token. The difference is that a Bearer-only client doesn't allow obtaining an access token on behalf of himself.

For your case, if you want to use the API client for any authentication process, then you need to make it public or confidential. If not, you can always log in with the App-1 client and access the API (you already have a valid token).

From the [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#oidc-clients):

> Bearer-only access type means that the application only allows bearer
>   token requests. If this is turned on, this application cannot
>   participate in browser logins.